# ¿Cómo dar permiso de vista a otro usuario en sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero dar permiso para que un usuario vea la vista creada por otro y no puedo.
He intentado lo siguiente y no funciona:

```
Grant select on usuario1.vista to usuario2;
```

Comment: Cuál es el error que obtienes? sin ese error, cómo saber cuál es el problema?

Answer (score -1):

Sugiero que concedas el permiso de lectura (al usuario2) para cada una de las tablas que componen la vista del usuario1.